# Stopping Multiple Programs Running At Once

Tags: vb.net, process

Here's the problem. In our program, we have an add-on (machine Vision) that customers can edit themselves. We provide a template for this add-on in VB.NET 2010. They then copy this template and rename it (to whatever they like), and edit a couple of things.. The problem is that I would like to restrict the customer from opening more than one copy of this template at one time.

Obviously I've selected single instance, but since they are actually different programs this will only stop them from opening the same template twice. My first thought was that I could change the process name and place something generic (myCompany - ) in front of the assembly name, but I don't think that's possible. I was wondering if anyone knew of another way to check that this program is open. Obviously we can edit our template to place something in all copies of their template (which could be checked) but I can't think of anything available.

Comment: Why do you wanna to restrict the costumer from opening more than one copy of your template?

Comment: Is this an add-in for Microsoft Office? Or for Visual Studio? Or something else? I don't really know what you mean by "template". How are the users opening it? Does it contain any code that runs at launch? I would recommend using a semaphore or other type of lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand why you would want to prevent a template from being shown more than once. I've never tried anything like this, but i would try using System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill, and kill any new instance of the program. So you will need your program to monitor whether the process name is launched more than once, and terminate every launch but the first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments. I actually just got this working this morning. It's more of a clutter thing. The vision program (template) connects to a hardware camera. That camera can only connect once, so when the second template opens, it opens with an error.

The fix I came up with is this -  the customers put all these folders within a Vision folder, and are instructed to name the folder the same name as the assembly or process name, so I just searched in the folder and will kill the startup of the form if there is already a program with any of the folder names open. Maybe a little messy, but it's what worked.